# How to read .llvm_addrsig section from relocatable object file or an ELF?

Tags: clang, llvm, elf, relocation

I have got a vague idea about what .llvm_addrsig section is from this post and linker use this to prevent ICF..
https://discourse.llvm.org/t/problems-with-mach-o-address-significance-table-generation/63392
But Anyone have any idea or reference that, How we decode or read this section??
Like How linker take this as input from relocatable file and perform things.??